# I am trying to put an audio url in Applet

Tags: java, user-interface, audio, applet

I am having trouble putting in the audio file url into my app in my getCodeBase method :

```
public class Audioapp extends JApplet
{
    public class Sound // Holds one audio file
    {
        private AudioClip song; // Sound player
        private URL songPath; // Sound path
        Sound(String filename)
        {
            try
            {
                songPath = new URL(getCodeBase("G:\\Uni\\Programming\\Rolling assignements\\Week0\\Programming week21"),filename);  // This is the place were im getting error
                song = Applet.newAudioClip(songPath); // Load the Sound
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();} 
        }
        public void playSound()
        {
            song.play(); // Play
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
The method getCodeBase() in the type Applet is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

I followed the tutorial online and have followed it properly and in full. But what is missing/wrong?

Comment: You didn't read the tutorial. `filename` is meant to be the whole directory to the file. So like, C:\...\audio\song.mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What tutorial did you follow?
Did you read the javadoc for getCodeBase and AudioClip?

I think this is what you should do :

```
Audioclip song = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(),"filename");
```

The song is supposed to be in your class files directory.
I didn't try it, but I think it should work.

Comment: Its worked thanks, now how would i implement the play sound method in an actionListener for a gui?

Comment: @dhali  That is a separate question.  Ask a separate question (after looking at [How to write an ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)).

Answer (score 0):

According Oracle's [Java API for Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/applet/Applet.html) there is no method there you can pass a string.
There are three methods without any parameters.